# How to convert an argument of a function from int to real in sml?

Tags: sml

This is the code I wrote in sml for calculating a harmonic sum. I basically want to calculate real numbers
as for integers all would evaluate to 0(not of any use). But this code is giving error.

Trial 1:

```
  if y<x then 0
  else f(x,y-1)+ 1/y;
```

Error:

```
Elaboration failed: Type clash. Functions of type "real * real → real" cannot take an argument of type "int * int": Cannot merge "int" and "real".
```

Trial 2:

```
  if y<x then 0
  else f(real(x),y-1)+ 1/y;
```

error:

```
Elaboration failed: "real" is not a constructor.
```

Even replacing 0 with 0.0 didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer to my question.
We basically need to use

```
 if y<x then 0.0
  else f(x,y-1)+ 1.0/real(y);
```

since the type of our function is (int*int)->real